# What is the best way to detect character set of an E-Mail message?

Tags: php, ascii, imap, detection, iso-8859-1

I am currently developing a **PHP** script that connects to a remote IMAP server and  fetches the body of a message, parses it and sends the data into a DB. The inbox contais 50000+ messages, some of them having US-ASCII and ISO-8859-1 encoding. The plain body of the message must be converted into UTF-8 encoding before submission to database.

What is the best way of detecting the character set of a message's plain text body?

Comment: should be in the emails header set ?

Comment: What Java APIs are you using?  Do they understand MIME encoding?  If so, I would have thought that this should all be taken care of for you; i.e. the API should give you the plain-text content of the emails as a sequence of Java characters in UTF-16 encoding.  (As per String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer, Reader, etcetera.)

Comment: JAVA? who said anything about java?

Comment: Sorry we've talking about PHP here. Editing post

Comment: Perhaps delete them. Are they going to be read?

Comment: I found it out myself. Using imap_mime_header_decode() -function I was able to fetch the character set of the message. Thanks.